# Split Binary values in a matrix

Tags: java, string, matrix, binary

I have 3x2 matrix which I converted into binary format. Each binary representation should have 7 bits. I used the String.format method to get the binary matrix.

0000111 1101000
0000101 1100101 
0001100 1110010

Now I need to split each binary value into it's bits in a way that the 3x2 matrix is converted to 3x14.

```
`int[][] p = {{7,104},{5,101},{12,114}};
 int n;
 String[][] P = new String[3][2];
 for (int i =0; i<3;i++)
 {
 for(int j=0 ; j<2;j++)
 {
 P[i][j] =String.format("%7s", Integer.toBinaryString(p[i][j])).replace(' ',     '0');
 }
 }`
```

How do I split the binary string into separate bits to get a 3x14 matrix ? 
Can String.split() method  be used ? How do i go about using that method for a matrix ?

Comment: Why don't you go directly from int to the bits?

Comment: How do I do that ? Will that give a 3x14 matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int[][] p = {{7,104},{5,101},{12,114}};
static int bit( int[][] p, int row, int col ){
    return (p[row][col/7] >> (7 - col%7 - 1)) & 1;
}
```

col/7 produces 0 and 1 for the ranges 0-6 and 7-14. col%7 results in values 0,1,...6. Thus, the shift shifts 6,5,...0 times.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
  for( int r = 0; r < 3; ++r ){
    for( int c = 0; c < 14; ++c ){
      System.out.print( " " + bit(p, r,c) );
    }
  System.out.println();
}
```

You can, of course, store this in a 3x14 array.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved it !! Although I'm trying to understand the logic that you have used. Programming in Java for the first time.

Comment: I was gonna say it was a great solution, but I can't get my head around it :D

Comment: Feel free to ask questions. The contents of main should be clear; you are expecting a 3x14 matrix. Is something missing from the comment after `bit`?

Comment: No.. Nothing is missing. More questions coming up. :) I understood the logic you have used. Very Clear. Thanks ! :)